# Scheduled Task to shutdown computer after 2 hours of inactivity?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, scheduled-task

We have around 900 machines in two locations.  95% of these machines are shared, and we find users don't log off or shutdown as often as they should to get updates.

I thought I would create a scheduled task and roll it out via Group Policy to run the shutdown command after 2 hours of inactivity for one group and 4 hours of inactivity for another, but under the scheduled tasks "Conditions" it only has the option for 1 hour.  There is another option that says "Wait for idle for" but that confuses me.

[image: Screeny]

Is there a way to do this with a Scheduled Task and Group Policy, or will I have to go another route?

Comment: This isn't directly answering your question, but we use [1E Nightwatchman](http://www.1e.com/it-efficiency/software/nightwatchman-enterprise-pc-power-management/) to manage logoff and shutdown of idle PCs, but we started using it in the XP days, it's possible the built-in traggers like this are more versatile now in Win7 & 8.

Comment: and this is a 7x24 operation right?

Comment: "users don't log off or shutdown as often as they should to get updates." - wouldn't a WSUS server and WSUS gpo handle this issue? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: tony roth:  This is a 7x24 Operation.

Comment: TheCleaner: Since we are 24/7 we can't enforce reboots after patches are applied.  That also wouldn't help for other updates applied through GPO or a client specific application.

Comment: "we find users don't log off or shutdown as often as they should to get updates." - How will the computers get updates if they're shut down?

Comment: The computers don't need the updates if they are turned off, however the next time they are turned on they should get them.